# network adapter counters

Tags: c++, winpcap, nic

I'm writing for a company a software that sends and analyzes raw ethernet packets using winpcap. I'm experiencing seldom packet loss when the software runs over longer time. My environment is rather bad: a laptop with lots of corporate software including AV that I can't switch off.

I would like to analyze the packet loss problem by reading: **(error) counters of the network adapters**. What would be the best way to do that in C++ or C#? My best idea was the statistics mode of the winpcap, but it provides too little information. Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the WMI performance statistics for the [network interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - they probably contain all the counters that you're interested in.

There is an example linked in the article of an implementation in C++, but I'm pretty sure that it can be done in C# without much difficulty also.